# Matlab Plotting x=a?

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I draw i.e. x = 5 line in plot at Matlab?

I plot like that:

```
x = (-10:.1:10); 
f= 10;
plot(x, f, 'r');
```

of course it doesn't work. For every variable of x, y is equal to 0 except for x=10. When x = 10 y equals to everything. How to plot this?

Comment: Note that in your example `f = 10` won't work, because `f` and `x` must have the same dimensions. You should rather use `f = 10 * ones(size(x))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, [`plot(X, Y)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html;jsessionid=f35e00dda81b3ad5ea6995afaeaa) simply draws points on the graph (and connects them with lines). Note that in this form of syntax, `X` and `Y` must have the same dimensions. Therefore, to plot the line `x = 5` create a vector of your desired y-coordinates, and then create matching x-coordinates, which are all equal to 5:

```
Y = -10:0.1:10;
X = 5 * ones(size(Y));
plot(X, Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

A useful function from the FileExchange in [`hline` and `vline`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039-hline-and-vline).

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this by plotting only 2 points:

```
f = 5;    
plot([-10 10] , [1 1]*f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using line is more straightforward here than plot.

```
    x = [-10, 10]; 
    f = ones(size(x));
    f = 5 .* f;
    line(x, f);
```